# Magnet links for torrents in (email) RSS feed

Tags: email, bittorrent, magnet-links

Is it possible to subscribe to an RSS Feed on a torrent website which feeds into my email and has magnet links? (I'm running Windows 10).

Comment: Does the feed give you magnet links? Or just the name.

Comment: An RSS Feed on a torrent website can directly feed a torrent client and automatically download the torrents. Why use email?

Comment: Why the downvote? No explanation?

Answer (score 0):

If the RSS feed provides these magnet links, then it's just a matter of finding an RSS-to-email converter. There are online services, like https://blogtrottr.com/ or you can install some tool on your machine.

You didn't mention which OS you're using, but for Linux for instance there is rss2email package:

> rss2email is a simple program which you can run in your crontab.  It
>   watches RSS (or Atom) feeds and sends you a nicely formatted  email
>   message for each new item.

Answer (score 0):

A good tool is
[IFTTT](https://ifttt.com/)
(If This Then That), described as:

> If This Then That, also known as IFTTT is a free web-based service to
>   create chains of simple conditional statements, called applets.
>
> An applet is triggered by changes that occur within other web services
>   such as Gmail, Facebook, Telegram, Instagram, or Pinterest.
>
> For example, an applet may send an e-mail message if the user tweets
>   using a hashtag, or copy a photo on Facebook to a user's archive if
>   someone tags a user in a photo.

Here are a few examples of applets that do similar actions, for demonstrating
how to create an applet that will email all feeds that contain magnet links:

- [If RSS filter match, Then email](https://ifttt.com/applets/326276p-if-rss-filter-match-then-email)
  If rss feed entry contains some word (Keyword or simple phrase), then email it.
- [RSS feed to email](https://ifttt.com/applets/147561p-rss-feed-to-email)
  Simply add an RSS feed URL from any website or blog and have new posts automatically delivered to your inbox.

Comment: @Gavriel: Any comment?